# WebOTP API How to detect that the user clicks Deny?

Tags: javascript, mobile, webotp-api

When using the WebOTP API to get a PIN code from an SMS, the user is asked to "Allow" or "Deny" the web page to get the pin code. If the user allows, the promise retrieved from `navigator.credentials.get` is resolved with the pin code. However, if the user clicks Deny, the promise does not resolve. Neither does it reject, as far as I can see.

Is there any way to detect that the user clicks deny?

Here is my code:

```
autoFillPin() {
  if (!this.webOtpApiSupported) {
    this.remoteLog("Web OTP API not Supported");
    return;
  }

  this.remoteLog(
    "Web OTP API Supported " +
      (window.isSecureContext ? "and context is secure" : ", but context is not secure")
  );
  this.abortController = new AbortController();
  navigator.credentials
    .get({
      otp: { transport: ["sms"] },
      signal: this.abortController.signal,
    })
    .then((otp) => {
      if (!otp || !otp.code) {
        this.remoteLog(`Web OTP API resolved without code`);
        return;
      }
      this.remoteLog(`Web OTP API resolved with code of length ${otp.code.length}`);

      const keyEvent = {
        isTrusted: true,
        target: {
          id: "pinInput",
          value: otp.code,
        },
      };

      this.onPinChanged(keyEvent);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.remoteLog("navigator.credentials.get error:" + err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      this.abortController = null;
    });
},
```

Comment: Have you written any code yet?  Cutting down what you've done to demonstrate the issue in a simple manner ( without actual API calls, and putting it in the question) would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I added my code, including the logging that I use to see what is actually happening.

Comment: While I would expect a "Deny" button click to reject the promise returned by `get`, the only reference to its existence that I could found was in the flow chart in Google article at https://developer.chrome.com/articles/web-otp/#see-it-in-action . It doesn't show what happens if "Deny", but there is a [FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/web-otp/#faq) about things that can go wrong that you would never guess. Reading around suggests the abort controller is mostly for implementing a timeout on the request to abort it if the user navigates away. Now I want to know too :-)